# Foreign Key to Primary key relation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I saw a table that has a PK of type int and then a FK that is pointed from the same column to the same column.

For example

```
Table1
ID int identity
Name nvarchar(50)
```

ID is the primary key. When I try to see the relations, I see a foreign key from Table1.ID to Table1ID, what does it means?

Comment: If you script it out and it's literally `FOREIGN KEY (ID) references Table1 (ID)` then it's pointless, and was probably added in error. If that's not the case, can you script it out anyway and add the script to your question.

Comment: thank you, I also thought it was a mistake but I was not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is really a FK from the same field to the same field, it does not make much sense.

However, in general, a FK that references its own table *can* be useful. Consider the following employee table, for example:

```
ID int identity
Name nvarchar(50)
SupervisorID int nullable -> FK to ID
```

SupervisorID can point to another employee and create a hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought it was a mistake but I was not sure